# Image flickers when mouse moves in HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, canvas

I already looked in these [thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7495355/prevent-canvas-from-flickering-on-redraw) and [thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506619/image-flickers-during-drag-in-canvas), but I still got the flickering when the mouse move.

My code:

```
    function draw(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "/Sample/Icons/sample.png";


    img.onload = function () {     
        ctx.drawImage(img, X1, Y1, 25, 25);                       
    };
  }
```

Hopefully someone can give me an idea or solution on how to solve my flickering problem.

Comment: Obviously we need more of your code to help you with your flickering problem. All your example code does is load and display a single image on the canvas. It has no mousemove code at all! :-O

Comment: the code is too long, but my other tools that used lineTo() is working just this one that uses drawImage();

Comment: use a doublebuffer i.e first draw everything to an offscreen surface and then draw this onto the canvas

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795269/does-html5-canvas-support-double-buffering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're calling `draw` for each mousemove.

Mousemove events occur about 30 times a second so there is not enough time to load an image inside a mousemove handler.

Instead, load the image once at the start of your app.

Then `ctx.drawImage` has enough time to draw that preloaded image during each mousemove event.

Comment: Interesting answer, is there any sample implementation that I can try?

Comment: Here's a previous SO post that illustrates how to preload multiple images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600681/using-images-as-buttons-on-html-canvas/31601615#31601615

Comment: Thanks mate! I'll try to understand and implement it on mine